# I merge 2 vertex and become weird ,How can i fix?

Tags: edit-mode, vertices

[image: Before I merge]

[image: After I merge]

First pic :Before merge
Second pic: After merge

Comment: Your question is unclear to me.  Please try to rephrase.  Please show a different image.  Please clean up the title of your question.

Comment: Sorry yo make you unclear. I'm newbie to use blender.

Comment: Please rephrase the entire question.

Comment: Whatever you did ... undo it .. Control Z.  Try it 3 different times to see if you get better results.

Comment: @atomicbezierslinger Sorry for make question unclear. I'm newbie to use blender. I merge 2 vertex and them become like in picture .i don't know how to fix them.

Comment: I already undo them.But not work.Them become same.

Comment: turn off clipping, move the vert, then turn clipping back on https://imgur.com/GTOGu88

Answer (score 1):

To me, it looks like you have not cleared one side of your mesh before setting up the mirror modifier.
So if you still have both sides of the mesh and you're trying to merge things from both sides, the result is quite straightforward.

The mirror modifier is meant to literally duplicate symmetrically your mesh. Its purpose is for you to handle only a fraction of the mesh. But you have to cut out the part you want to let to the mirror modifier first.

So, if that's the issue:

In edit mode, <kbd>Numpad 1</kbd> for front view, use <kbd>Z</kbd> to set the wireframe mode (it will allow you to select hidden geometry).
Select one side of your mesh up to the center with B and delete it.

[image: demo gif]

Answer (score 0):

- Select the upper and lower portions of the wrist area. Do this first. Then try merge.  Two loops are selected.

---

Later.

- Do not select the left and right sides at the same time.
- Only do the left hand side first.
- Then do the right hand second.

Comment: You mean i have to unable mirror and merge left hand first?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is that you're misled by the *Adjust Edit Cage To Modifier Result* option of the Mirror modifier (fourth button) that makes the mirrored vertices workable, and you've created the hand on the mirrored side instead of original side. So, disable this option, now you'll see what I mean. Grab the hand and switch it to the right side, do a <kbd>S</kbd> <kbd>X</kbd> <kbd>-1</kbd> to mirror it so that it is flipped in the right direction when it is in the right side. Now you can make the joint between the hand and arm.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to merge too far and unlinked verticies. And If you are doing something identical use mirror modifier.